# kubernetes ingress not accepting the self signed ssl

Tags: kubernetes, ssl, kubernetes-ingress

My kubernetes ingress is not accepting the self signed certificate and instead when opening the url on firefox the **Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate** is added.

> All the things done locally on pc with minikube in Kali Linus. Kali
> linus is running in a Virtual Machine by VMWare software.The doc which
> I am referring is -
> https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-multi-ssl

The Ingress Yaml file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: first-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
    secretName: myssl
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: first-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

The "192.168.49.2" is the ingress ip address. So https://192.68.49.2 opens my app on the browser.

The certificate is generated with Openssl with the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out s.key 2048
openssl req -new -key s.key -out s.csr -subj "/CN=example.com"
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in s.csr -signkey s.key -out s.crt
```

The certificate is added to k8s secret.

```
kubectl create secret tls myssl --cert s.crt --key s.key
```

The `curl -kv https://192.168.49.2` command output is:

```
* Trying 192.168.49.2:443...
* Connected to 192.168.49.2 (192.168.49.2) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2
* ALPN: offers http/1.1
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN: server accepted h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  start date: Oct 22 09:57:19 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 22 09:57:19 2023 GMT
*  issuer: O=Acme Co; CN=Kubernetes Ingress Controller Fake Certificate
*  SSL certificate verify result: self-signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multiplexing
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* h2h3 [:method: GET]
* h2h3 [:path: /]
* h2h3 [:scheme: https]
* h2h3 [:authority: 192.168.49.2]
* h2h3 [user-agent: curl/7.85.0]
* h2h3 [accept: */*]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x561c242ff950)
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.49.2
> user-agent: curl/7.85.0
> accept: */*
> 
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
< HTTP/2 200 
< date: Sat, 22 Oct 2022 10:05:50 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 ..... html of the page
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.49.2 left intact
```

Kindly help.

**Update 2 days Later:**

I debugged and found I have installed nginx ingress with the command:

```
minikube addons enable ingress
```

It installs the ingress in `ingress-nginx` namespace while my secret is in `default` namespace. Can this be the problem, if so what is the solution?

Comment: You might want to use a valid domain name instead of `/CN=192.168.49.2`  https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/what-is-common-name/

Comment: @P.... I already tried with example.com but no sucess.

Comment: @yogihosting Can you curl https://demo.youtrdomain.com -kv? Output please.

Comment: @RichardRublev i have added curl response on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in your ingress manifest, here:

```
rules:
- host: example.com
- http:
    paths:
```

You have created two rules, the first matches `host: example.com` but defines no paths or backends; the second matches path `/` but doesn't set a `host`. You want:

```
rules:
- host: example.com
  http:
    paths:
```

---

> It installs the ingress in ingress-nginx namespace while my secret is in default namespace. Can this be the problem, if so what is the solution?

This is not a problem: it is the expected configuration. Your SSL secrets should be installed in the same namespace as your application and Ingress.

---

I've been playing with this a bit over the past couple of days, and I'm not sure you can get this to operate the way you want without using a hostname. Fortunately, setting up a hostname to use during local development is relatively straightforward.

In most cases you can edit your `/etc/hosts` file. For example, if your application is hosted on 192.168.49.2, then you would add an entry like this to `/etc/hosts` to access your application at `https://example.com`:

```
192.168.49.2    example.com
```

You can add multiple hostname aliases, which allows you to use multiple hostname-based Ingress resources on your cluster:

```
192.168.49.2    example.com myapp.internal anotherapp.dev
```

When you're testing with `curl`, you can use the `--resolve` option to accomplish the same thing:

```
curl --resolve example.com:443:192.168.49.2 -kv https://example.com
```

So for example, if I deploy the following Ingress on my local cluster:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami
spec:
  tls:
    - secretName: myssl
      hosts:
        - example.com
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: whoami
                port:
                  name: http
```

With the following entry in `/etc/hosts`:

```
$ grep example.com /etc/hosts
193.168.1.200 example.com
```

Running `curl -skv https://example.com` shows that the ingress is using my custom certificate rather than the default ingress certificate:

```
[...]
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=example.com
*  start date: Oct 23 12:52:45 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 23 12:52:45 2023 GMT
*  issuer: CN=example.com
[...]
```

Comment: I also want to add that I am doing this on locally so there won't be host in my case. So how to do it since in my case ingress call is done with it's ip address and not with the host name.

Comment: Great answer. Solved with your help.

Answer (score 1):

Important is that the host name of the defined TLS certificate is matching the subject alt name in the certificate. If this is not the case the

```
kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
# search the controller pod name
kubectl logs pod/ingress-nginx-controller-84b9766c9c-bmlr2 -n ingress-nginx
```

> W0815 23:00:44.109801       7 controller.go:1448] SSL certificate "default/my-tls-secret" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server "foo.localhost": x509: certificate is valid for localhost, not foo.localhost

In this case `foo.localhost` should have been used, but it was `localhost`.